# App doesn't work on iPhone 4S

Tags: codenameone

I have an iOS application codename One, which is running in normally iPhone 5 and 6, which use the iOS operating system version 10.

However, that my app is not working on iPhone 4 and 4s, which use the iOS operating system 9.

Any idea what might be happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps should work fine all the way back to OS 6.0 without a problem (Apple made the cutoff of 6.0 mandatory).

I'm guessing you failed at the install stage which could mean one of the following:

- Missing or incorrect UDID setting - if you got the device UDID from an app it's probably incorrect if it's not in the provisioning well... it's missing.
- Previously installed app with the same package/id either from the appstore or a previous build with a difference certificate
- Parental control settings or corporate restriction limiting installs
- Apple OTA install bug - the workaround for this is simple, connect the device with a cable and try to install the IPA thru itunes. Sometimes it starts working OTA after doing this once (FYI: OTA == Over the air)